# How do I access Windows Media Player Library programmatically in C#/WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, media

I need to access and present the information from Windows Media Player library, from my C#/WPF application.
How do I do this programmatically in C#/WPF?

Comment: What do you want to display? the songs ID3Tags? the library? playlists?

Comment: the library and also the ID3Tags

Comment: I haven't figured out a clean way to do this ... so i wrote my own indexing system that builds a database ... i'd prefer to use wmp though ... M$ already solved little issues like handling bad ID3 tags and working with different media types.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit of a cop out ...

The SDK is a huge subject ... how about a sample ?

EDIT : 1 of 2 :

This is what im talking about as a starting point:
The documentation for the "Windows Media Player SDK" refers you to download the "Windows SDK" and then consume some key interfaces ...

Here's the list of interfaces:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd563069(v=VS.85).aspx

The download can be started here:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6B6C21D2-2006-4AFA-9702-529FA782D63B

That links you to an installer app that basically goes and gets the files for you (similar to say the silverlight or flash installer)

EDIT 2 of 2:

Once the WMP SDK isdownloaded and installed add a reference to "WMPLib" its listed under com in the dialog if like everyone else you happen to be using visual studio :)

Once you have your reference you can do this ...

```
WMPlib.WindowsMediaPlayer wmpInstance = new WMPlib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
IWMPMediaCollection lib = wmpInstance.mediaCollection;
```

From here on out its simply a case of using that reference to the library ... 
lib.GetAll() returns everything in your media library :)

...

And thats how its done :) !!!